# Nested, asynchronous promises: how to know when they're all resolved?

Tags: javascript, promise, es6-promise

I'm doing some api calls from a web app. First I'm getting my partner details (a group of hotels). This partner has some properties. For each of these properties, I need to get their rooms; then for each of these rooms, I need to get their availabilities and bookings.
I would like to perform all these calls asynchronously (ie as soon as I have the room info of a property, I can get their bookings and availabilities, without waiting to have the details of all the properties).
I would like to know when everything is loaded. Below is a simplified code using timeouts to simulate api calls.

I've tried to push each new promise in an array, and use Promise.all on this array, but I run into the same issue.

I've also tried to increment a counter everytime a query is made, and decrease the counter everytime one is resolved; this is working but doesn't seem very clean?

```
        const getPartner = () => {
            const p = new Promise((resolve) => {
                setTimeout(() => {
                    console.log('getPartner finished');
                    resolve({
                        properties: [1, 2, 3],
                    });
                }, 1000);
            });
            return p;
        }

        const getRooms = () => {
            const p = new Promise((resolve) => {
                setTimeout(() => {
                    console.log('getRooms finished');
                    resolve([1, 2, 3]);
                }, 1000);
            });
            return p;
        }

        const getAvailabilities = () => {
            const p = new Promise((resolve) => {
                setTimeout(() => {
                    console.log('getAvailabilities finished');
                    resolve([1, 2, 3]);
                }, 1000);
            });
            return p;
        }

        const getBookings = () => {
            const p = new Promise((resolve) => {
                setTimeout(() => {
                    console.log('getBookings finished');
                    resolve([1, 2, 3]);
                }, 1000);
            });
            return p;
        }

        function main() {
            getPartner().then((partner) => {
                Promise.all([
                    partner.properties.forEach((property) => {
                        getRooms().then((rooms) => {
                            rooms.forEach((room) => {
                                getAvailabilities();
                                getBookings();
                            })
                        });
                    })
                ]).then(() => {
                    console.log('all finished');
                });
            });
        }

        main();
```

I expect "all finished" to show last in the console. Instead it shows immediately after "getPartner finished"

Edit: here's what I tried with a counter:

```
const promises = [];

        const getPartner = () => {
            const p = new Promise((resolve) => {
                setTimeout(() => {
                    console.log('getPartner finished');
                    resolve({
                        properties: [1, 2, 3],
                    });
                }, 1000);
            });
            promises.push(p);
            return p;
        }

        const getRooms = () => {
            const p = new Promise((resolve) => {
                setTimeout(() => {
                    console.log('getRooms finished');
                    resolve([1, 2, 3]);
                }, 1000);
            });
            promises.push(p);
            return p;
        }

        const getAvailabilities = () => {
            const p = new Promise((resolve) => {
                setTimeout(() => {
                    console.log('getAvailabilities finished');
                    resolve([1, 2, 3]);
                }, 1000);
            });
            promises.push(p);
            return p;
        }

        const getBookings = () => {
            const p = new Promise((resolve) => {
                setTimeout(() => {
                    console.log('getBookings finished');
                    resolve([1, 2, 3]);
                }, 1000);
            });
            promises.push(p);
            return p;
        }

        function main() {
            getPartner().then((partner) => {
                partner.properties.map((property) => {
                    getRooms().then((rooms) => {
                        getAvailabilities();
                        getBookings();
                    })
                })
            })
            .then(() => {
                Promise.all(promises).then(() => {
                    console.log('all finished');
                });
            });
        }

        main();
```

Comment: Tbh, instead of doing dozens of http calls you should rather change your API to return these results as once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Several issues:

- `forEach` does not return anything, yet you should return an array -- to feed to `Promise.all`.
- Use `Promise.all` in *every* case where you have multiple promises
- *Return* the promises whenever you need to chain one in a `then` callback

Here is how it would work:

```
function main() {
    getPartner().then((partner) => {
        return Promise.all(partner.properties.map((property) => {
            return getRooms().then((rooms) => {
                return Promise.all(rooms.map((room) => {
                    return Promise.all([getAvailabilities(), getBookings()]);
                }))
            });
        })).then(() => {
            console.log('all finished');
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Perfect, that's exactly what I needed. Thank you so much!